# How to replace existing information, with same questions

Tags: excel, vba

i have the questions to add a new row, but need a way to edit existing rows with the user being asked which time (kerta) and filling out the same questions to replace old info

```
Dim Päivä As String
Dim Kerta As String
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim lastrow4 As Long

Päivä = InputBox("Mikä päivä?", "PÄIVÄKIRJA")
lastrow1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow1, "B").Value = Päivä

Kerta = InputBox("Monesko harjoituskerta", "PÄIVÄKIRJA")
lastrow4 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow4, "F").Value = Kerta
```

i have a question which asks the number of the session, and i need to recognize the row based on this cell's value, and replace the row with the questions. (päivä = day / kerta = session)

Comment: The question is not quite clear. Can you please provide some screenshots on how it looks, and/or how you want it to look? I suggest you to read some basic VBA tutorial, given that (what I understand from your question at least) you already have what you are asking, just need to replicate it.

Comment: I suggest an userform with a template for your fields and a drop-down box with all session numbers. Add or edit or delete under three buttons....

Comment: i'm looking for a way to replace the info in the existing table. I have a msg box that asks 5 questions, and fills the cells in a row. Thing is, i need a way to replace that info, by asking the same questions. Now the code only adds another row. And i would need to recognize the row which needs to be replaced, by asking which session (which the users fills out on question 5).

So yes, the user fills out diffrent info, but to a row, which he already filled out. Replacing the row.